# MySQL: Syntax error when creating trigger

Tags: php, mysql

Why my sql syntax is throwing an error?

```
CREATE TRIGGER info
AFTER INSERT ON inbox
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN if SUBSTRING(new.TextDecoded,1,6)='telkom' then
INSERT INTO outbox ( DestinationNumber, Coding, TextDecoded, CreatorID )VALUES ( new.SenderNumber, 'Default_No_Compression', (SELECT nama from data_dosen WHERE kode = SUBSTRING(new.TextDecoded,8,10)), '1');

else
INSERT INTO outbox (DestinationNumber, Coding, TextDecoded, CreatorID) VALUES (new.SenderNumber, 'Default_No_Compression', 'Maaf format sms Anda salah. Ketik telkom<spasi>kode dosen', '1');

end if;

END$$
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: You probably need a `delimiter` statement before the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have delimiter definition before your trigger. Delimiter informs MySQL which characters will end up your trigger. Without it, MySQL assumes semicolon as default delimiter and fails upon first semicolon in your code. Check out this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER info
AFTER INSERT ON inbox
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN if SUBSTRING(new.TextDecoded,1,6)='telkom' then
    INSERT INTO outbox ( DestinationNumber, Coding, TextDecoded, CreatorID )VALUES ( new.SenderNumber, 'Default_No_Compression', (SELECT nama from data_dosen WHERE kode = SUBSTRING(new.TextDecoded,8,10)), '1');

else
    INSERT INTO outbox (DestinationNumber, Coding, TextDecoded, CreatorID) VALUES (new.SenderNumber, 'Default_No_Compression', 'Maaf format sms Anda salah. Ketik telkom<spasi>kode dosen', '1');

end if;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```